# Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi 3 Segmentation fault

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to get google assistant running on Raspberry Pi 3. I am running into an error

```
(env)pi@raspberrypi:~$ googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project-id buddy-fca9f --device-model-id xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx.

device_model_id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
device_id: DBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

 Segmentation fault
```

I am following https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/run-sample for the setup.

I've already registered my device with register tool but its not helping out.
On the other hand ***pushtotalk*** is working as expected. It'd be great if you can help me out or point me in right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by upgrading the library to v1.0.1, through running this in the env

```
python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-library==1.0.1
```

[This](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/313) helped.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.

Not sure why if we didn't provide `--project-id` it working but has a warning said that the device is not registered yet.

this is the result when we use both `--project-id` and `--device-model-id` at the same time as instructed on this page : https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/

```
device_model_id: smartbox-228605-my-model
device_id: EF949BCF913C3206EEA22E2B28E402CX

Segmentation fault
```

and this is the result when we only use `--device-model-id` (*the old version for the tutorial above*):

```
device_model_id: smartbox-228605-my-model
device_id: EF949BCF913C3206EEA22E2B28E402CX


    This device is not registered. This means you will not be able to use
    Device Actions or see your device in Assistant Settings. In order to
    register this device follow instructions at:

    https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device

ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {"is_muted": false}
ON_MEDIA_STATE_IDLE
ON_START_FINISHED
```

and this is what I have done:

- `$ apt-get update`
- Create New project on the console
- Make sure Google Assistant API is enable on the project (*even to activate some other fires such as: Action API*)
- Register device using `googlesamples-assistant-devicetool`
- Try on the newly installed raspbian operating system (*both desktop and lite*)

and this is what I have not done:

- Enable billing on the Google Cloud Console (*if this is the case then I am done* ;-) )

**but** while waiting for the bugs you can use another google assistant hotword sample by accessing this : `google-assistant-demo --project-id YOUR-ID-PROJECT --device-model-id YOUR-ID-MODEL`
reference : https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/314
or even just create you own hotword.py from the repository : https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/tree/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/library

hope it help.

Comment: First of all Thanks for the help. I didn't try earlier without model-id but when I tried without model-id today, it worked, but with very low audio level (IDK why). I'll look into the demo hotword thing and see how it works. After fixing the bug or getting the hotword running I need to put a custom hotword. Any Idea How I can do that?

Comment: Not sure they will provide us a way to change it :), but you can found many 3rd party library out there like snowboy and here i found a good example for it : https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@neavvy/google-assistant-on-raspberry-or-part-3-custom-wake-word

Comment: python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-library==1.0.1  Running this solved the issue for me. lemme know if it works for you.