# Raspberry Pi 3: Google Assistant Segmentation Fault

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I followed the instructions on https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/setup to setup Google Assisstant on my Raspberry Pi 3. Unfortunately, using the hotword command gives me a segmentation fault:

```
$ googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project-id xxxxx --device-model-id xxxxx
device_model_id: xxxxx
device_id: BE5AC9Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Segmentation fault
```

**What I tried so far:**

- Registering the device like in this post is successful, seg fault
  still appears:
  [Google Assistant on Raspberry pi Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440960/google-assistant-on-raspberry-pi-segmentation-fault)
- My Google Assistant API is tuned on
- Without project id it works, as
  stated here:
  [Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi 3 Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142718/google-assistant-on-raspberry-pi-3-segmentation-fault)

What I noticed is, that also my google assistant app on the phone says I have 0 local devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue as you. I solved it by upgrading the library to **v1.0.1**, through running this in the env

```
python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-library==1.0.1
```

Based on talk from [this issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/313) on the [GitHub](https://github.com) for the Assistant SDK.

Comment: Wow, awesome! This really worked, thank you very much!